# PC turns on slow with an upgraded PSU to 800W from 500W

Tags: power-supply, power

I've been using my rig (i7-2600, 16g ram, Radeon 7970, 500W) for the past 4 years without any problems.

Recently I swapped out my 500W psu for a 800w psu 80+ gold(http://www.enermax.com/home.php?fn=eng/product_a1_1_1&lv0=1&lv1=54&no=100).  Everythings good except when turning on the PC, it takes around 10 seconds for my rig to turn on. I'm using a 8 outlet belkin multitap surgemaster and have 6 other items plugged into it. (NAS, Router, Small LED Lamp, 27" LED Monitor, Switch Hub, PS4)

Except for NAS, Router and Switch Hub, others are not in use when powering on my rig.

I took my rig to a PC shop nearby and there, it turned on instantly. He connected to a 5 outlet multitap. However, if I connect it at home on my surgemaster, it takes around 10 seconds from the time I click on the power button till the fan starts to swirl and turn on. (had no such issue with the previous 500w psu)

Is this happening because 800W psu needs to pull more watts and amps vs the 500w psu, thus taking time to pull that extra from the surgemaster?
(there's no problem after my rig turns on. it's just that it's funny how it takes around 10 seconds for the pc to turn on with a more powerful psu)

Comment: Do you have a volt meter to check the line voltage?

Comment: sorry to say, but no. :(

Answer (score 3):

You pretty much answered your own question.  The surgemaster is probably controlling the ramp-up of the power to make sure its not the cause of a spike.

You have no posted the exact model of protector, but if its like this one you are running it well outside its specs - the technical specs provide for equipment of up to 350 watts.

I postulate that when the PSU is turned on there is a rush of current initially to charge the caps, and the Belkin clamps down on the available current - as the caps charge the system reaches equilibrium and turns on.

You might want to stress test the PSU to see if you can actually draw 800 watts from it (not sure how you would do this without specialist equipment though !)